# How to add functions to prototype of inner function in the global scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function A() {  
    this.B = function() {  
        var bla;
    };
}
A.B.prototype.foo = function() {console.log("Do whatever");};
```

I get this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

How to add a function to the prototype of B in this case?

Comment: An assignment after an invocation is never possible. If you want to set `A.B`, just do `A.B = ...` instead.

Comment: Do you have an understanding of how `this` works in JavaScript? If you're familiar with other languages, it's likely different than what you're assuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in our code... here is how:

```
function A() {
   this.B = function() {
      var blah;
   };
}

a = new A();
a.B.prototype.foo = function()  {console.log("Do whatever")};
```

Your first issue was doing:

```
this.B() = function...
```

That's not valid code, since you were calling method B and assing it a function, you had to reference the attribute.

Your other mistake, was not instantiating an "A" object, the function by itself can't be used as an object, it can only be called. That's why when you had:

```
A.B.prototype
```

You recieved that error message.

I hope that clears things up a bit for you, let me know if you have more doubts.

Comment: Thank you. I am still not used to writing flawless javascript without an interpreter. :) Furthermore, I had initially wanted to avoid using an instance of A to get to B. Is it safe to assume in this case it is not possible to add to the prototype of B without an instance of A?

Comment: `a.B.prototype.foo` doesn't actually work.  http://jsfiddle.net/pLMvE/  Unless you did `new a.B`.

Comment: Adding to my comment as you answered it during the comment writing process: 
Thank you again. It makes sense but I was just wondering if there was Javascript magic I was unaware of. Cheers. ps> sample code errors fixed.

Comment: To add here, then to call foo(), this has to be done :  
`var c = new a.B();  
c.foo();  `
That will work.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is a property of `A`, and can only be accessed from instances of `A`.

```
var aObj = new A;
aObj.B();
```

You cannot access `A.B` without using an instance of `A`.

You could access `aObj.B.prototype`, and add methods to that.

```
aObj.B.prototype.foo = function(){
    return 'test';
};
var bar = new aObj.B;
console.log(bar.foo()); // 'test'

var bObj = new A;
var foobar = new bObj.B;
console.log(foobar.foo()); // `foo` is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the inner function accessible by adding it to the outer prototype, then you can add functions to the inner object by using Outer.prototype.Inner.prototype without the immediate need for an instance of the outer object.

```
function A() {this.a="a";}
A.prototype.B = function() {this.b="b";}
A.prototype.B.prototype.foo = function() {console.log("b is:"+this.b);}
var a=new A();
var b=new a.B();
b.foo();
```